# Haskell: Chaining State Monad

Tags: haskell

If I have a function that shuffles a "deck of cards", how do I use the `State Monad` to iterate through a defined set number of shuffles and then return a result?

For example I have the following function that will do 1 shuffle of the deck then return a specific card:

```
step :: State [String] String
step = do
  modify shuffle
  deck <- get
  pure $ bestCard deck
```

What I would like to be able to do is iterate through the state changes 5 times before I return the value.

What I have tried is this:

```
steps :: Int -> State [String] String
steps n = case n of
  0 -> do
    deck <- get
    pure $ bestCard deck
  _ -> do
    modify shuffle
    steps (n - 1)
```

but that looks far from being the correct way of doing it, even though it works.

NB. I am aware this can be done without using `State Monad` but I am trying to use this example to learn how to use `State`.

edit:

Thanks to @Koterpillar, I can use `replicateM` to get what I want.

`evalState (replicateM n $ modify shuffle >> get >>= pure . bestCard)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most succinct way to do it is [`replicateM_`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM_), which repeats a monadic action a specified number of times and discards the result:

```
replicateM_ 5 $ modify shuffle
```

Because State is a monad, you only have to care about repeating an action, not specifically working with State. I found the above function by [searching Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts-13.18/hoogle?q=Monad%20m%20%3D%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20m%20a%20-%3E%20m%20%28%29) for the signature of the function I wanted:

```
Monad m => Int -> m a -> m ()
```

Note that the result doesn't even require a monad, just an applicative:

```
replicateM_ :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m ()
```

Comment: Thanks, actually needed to keep the values so `replicateM` it is.

Comment: You are still discarding values with `>>`.

Comment: there is no value to bind though?  `do modify shuffle; deck <- get; pure $ bestCard deck` returns a value. In any case it works fine for me?

Comment: Oh, I misread the precedence. If you want to get the best card out each time, you do need `replicateM`.